# Modify Line in File Matching WORD1 and NOT WORD2 (Sed/Awk)

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I need to add kernel parameters to lines not already containing them. (Don't want to add it to all lines in case it's already there.)

I've built this `awk` command to do it in buffer, but having trouble getting it into the file itself since awk lacks the ability to edit in place like `sed`. (However I can't figure out how to do this type of match with `sed`.)

`awk '/\tkernel/&&!/audit=1/ { print $0" audit=1"; }' /etc/grub.conf`

This looks for lines matching "kernel" and **NOT** "audit=1" (appending " audit=1" as necessary.)

Tagged as sed/awk, but open to other suggestions.

Comment: Why not just redirect it to another file?  This way you have the original file that is safe and a copy of what you want.

Comment: I can't use output redirection with the above as that only prints lines matching. (I'd lose the rest of grub.conf.)

Comment: Doh! My bad. I still suggest backups though :)

Comment: Of course! I'll do that with the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14132214/1207760) below by changing `-i.$(date +%F)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -i '/kernel/{/audit=1/!s/$/ audit=1/}' /etc/grub.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

The in-place editing functionality of `sed` uses a temporary file that without a suffix, is used to replace the existing file. For example, this:

```
sed -i '/\tkernel/ { /audit=1/!s/$/ audit=1/ }' /etc/grub.conf
```

is the same as this:

```
sed '/\tkernel/ { /audit=1/!s/$/ audit=1/ }' /etc/grub.conf > tmp && mv tmp /etc/grub.conf
```

The `-i` flag just sugar coats the process. Therefore, you can simply apply the same logic to your `awk` command:

```
awk '/\tkernel/ && !/audit=1/ { print $0, "audit=1"; next }1' /etc/grub.conf > tmp && mv tmp /etc/grub.conf
```

Comment: It works, and you could probably `sudo sh -c 'awk ... /etc/grub.conf'`, but the `sed` [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14132214/1207760) is still cleaner.

Comment: Yes, you could also try: `sudo -s ...`. The `sed` answer will be good until you want to do something more complicated. HTH.

Comment: @AaronCopley and others: GNU awk (`gawk`) v4.1.0 now supports in-place editing: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html